# Why do we use "is" instead of "has been" in this example?

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, spoken-english

Why do we use "is" instead of "has been" in the below example?

> Lisa is in Germany. She (is/has been) there on a business trip.

Comment: This question is off-topic. Can you say what you think it should be, and the reason you are questioning your choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are possible, in suitable contexts.

Without any particular context, *has been there* will be likely to interpreted in the special meaning of *have/had been* meaning "gone somewhere and returned", and so it will not fit with the first sentence.

But in answer to a question that sets the focus on recent time, like "What have your sisters been doing the last couple of weeks?", you version with *has been* is fine.